# hard to autolayout(stackView in ImageView)

Tags: swift, autolayout, imageview, stackview

I am making a custom cell using auto layout, but the auto layout is not applied well.

[image]

I set auto layout like this
Then, in the end, this shape come out.
but this shape that The ratio is not right.
why it doesn't match..?
i set a autolayout on storyboard...

[image]

As far as I know, if the image view in the stack view becomes hidden, the unhidden image view is filled in the rest of the stack view space. is it right?
if it's right. I make the code

```
if imageView == nil{

      imageView.isHidden = true }
```

Comment: Do you want the single image on the right to be at the same place if you have all 4 images? Or do you want it centered vertically?

Comment: To clarify... do you want it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qibs.png or this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeLar.png

Comment: I want to second look like this

Comment: If I upload 4 images If all 4 images are included, it will be correct shape..

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess at some of your constraints...

Here's my example layout:

[image]

The "Diamond" image view positions are:

```
1    3

2    4
```

Both Vertical stack views (`V-Stack-Left` and `V-Stack-Right`) have the same settings:

[image]

---

If we set `Alignment: Center` for the Horizontal stack view (`H-Stack`):

[image]

Setting `diamond4.isHidden = true` gives this result:

[image]

---

If we set `Alignment: Top` for the Horizontal stack view (`H-Stack`):

[image]

Setting `diamond4.isHidden = true` gives this result:

[image]

Comment: thank you sooooo much.. you're so smart.. I think I can solved it